# Changing i2c sda1/slc1 Pin

Tags: gpio, i2c

Im trying to change the i2c sda1 and slc1 Pins from Pin 3 / 5 to Pin 19 / 21
I want to connect a DS3231 HW Clock to such Pins, and 3 / 5 are already used by other things.

I configured:

```
# cat /boot/config.txt
[...]
dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,i2c_gpio_sda=19,i2c_gpio_scl=21
```

And rebooted the device, but the pins are still in original configuration:

```
# gpio readall
+-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 2---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
| BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
+-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
|     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
|   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 | ALT0 | 1 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5V      |     |     |
|   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 | ALT0 | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
|   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |  OUT | 1 |  7 || 8  | 1 | ALT0 | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
|     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 1 | ALT0 | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
|  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
|  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
|  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |   IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
|     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
|  10 |  12 |    MOSI |   IN | 1 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
|   9 |  13 |    MISO |   IN | 1 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
|  11 |  14 |    SCLK |   IN | 0 | 23 || 24 | 1 | IN   | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
|     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 1 | IN   | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
|   0 |  30 |   SDA.0 |   IN | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | IN   | SCL.0   | 31  | 1   |
|   5 |  21 | GPIO.21 |   IN | 1 | 29 || 30 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
|   6 |  22 | GPIO.22 |   IN | 1 | 31 || 32 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.26 | 26  | 12  |
|  13 |  23 | GPIO.23 |   IN | 0 | 33 || 34 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
|  19 |  24 | GPIO.24 |   IN | 0 | 35 || 36 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.27 | 27  | 16  |
|  26 |  25 | GPIO.25 |   IN | 0 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.28 | 28  | 20  |
|     |     |      0v |      |   | 39 || 40 | 0 | IN   | GPIO.29 | 29  | 21  |
+-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
| BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
+-----+-----+---------+------+---+---Pi 2---+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

Any ideas what i have to doto get this work?

Model is: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.

EDIT:
Bus was created:

```
# ls -l /dev/i2*
crw-rw---- 1 root i2c 89, 1 Aug 10 15:41 /dev/i2c-1
crw-rw---- 1 root i2c 89, 3 Aug 10 15:41 /dev/i2c-3
```

But the device does not appear:

```
# i2cdetect -y 3
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Enabled internal pull-ups:

```
  sudo pigpiod
  pigs pud 12 u
  pigs pud 13 u
```

But still no luck. When connected to pins 1-5, the hwclocks shows up fine:

```
# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What configuration are you expecting?  You are using software (bit banged) I2C.  I expect the GPIO will change to INPUT or OUTPUT for SDA and OUTPUT for SCL when you actually send I2C traffic.

Does the device appear?  E.g. does ls /dev/i2* show something other that bus 0 or bus 1?

Try i2cdetect -y 3 (as 3 is the likely bus created).

```
GPIO       pin  pin    GPIO
3V3         1    2      5V
2 (SDA)     3    4      5V
3 (SCL)     5    6      0V
4           7    8      14 (TXD)
0V          9   10      15 (RXD)
17 (ce1)   11   12      18 (ce0)
27         13   14      0V
22         15   16      23
3V3        17   18      24
10 (MOSI)  19   20      0V
9 (MISO)   21   22      25
11 (SCLK)  23   24      8 (CE0)
0V         25   26      7 (CE1)
           .......
0 (ID_SD)  27   28      1 (ID_SC)
5          29   30      0V
6          31   32      12
13         33   34      0V
19 (miso)  35   36      16 (ce2)
26         37   38      20 (mosi)
0V         39   40      21 (sclk)
```

Comment: Updated original question with your infos. Im just expecting that the hwclock shows up in i2cdetect on the new pins (works fine on pins 3/5)

Comment: Are there any pull-ups to 3V3 enabled?  Pins 3 and 5 (I2C bus 1) have hard-wired 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3.  You'll need to ensure there are pull-ups on the GPIO you are using for SDA/SCL.  You could enable the internal pull-ups as a quick test.

Comment: Ok. Perfect, something to work with. I have never done this, do i need to do something like this: https://github.com/fivdi/onoff/wiki/Enabling-Pullup-and-Pulldown-Resistors-on-The-Raspberry-Pi

Comment: You could try the following: `sudo pigpiod; pigs pud 19 u pud 21 u`.  Just to clarify, you are using GPIO 19 which is connected to pin 35 and GPIO 21 which is connected to pin 40.

Comment: I was trying to use the physical pins 19 / 21 :)
Ill change the dtoverlay part and the pigpiod to reflect the new numbers

Comment: Pin 19/21 are GPIO 10/9.

Comment: It will probably be more reliable if you use external resistors of, say, 2-5k.  The internal ones are quite weak at about 50k.